# Split Coordinates in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML node of coordinates which contains the fully geolocated lat/long combination. However on a new system it must be sent as individual nodes. The XMl is transfomed with XSLT before its sent so I was wondering how i could effectively seperate it into the component parts.

XML Node

```
<coordinates>-3.166610, 51.461231</coordinates>
```

I need to transform into:

```
<latitude>-3.166610</latitude>
<longitude>51.461231</longitude>
```

Thanks. Oh, should mention its XSLT 1.0

Comment: Then please show the XSLT that produces this result - and its input XML document.

Comment: This should be a simple matter of `substring-before` and `substring-after`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ian commented, `substring-before` and `substring-after` can handle this for you:

**This XML:**

```
<coordinates>-3.166610, 51.461231</coordinates>
```

**Given to this XSLT transformation:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="coordinates">
    <xsl:copy>
      <latitude>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-before(., ','))"/>
      </latitude>
      <longitude>
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(substring-after(., ','))"/>
      </longitude>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will produce the desired output XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coordinates>
   <latitude>-3.166610</latitude>
   <longitude>51.461231</longitude>
</coordinates>
```

Comment: Sometimes the easiest solutions are the hardest to spot. Thankyou kjhughes and @Ian-Roberts